# 18.04 Transmission stopped being able to handle large files

Tags: kernel, nautilus, files, filesystem, transmission

When using Transmission torrents in 18.04, I'm getting "Error: File too large".

When copying large files (22GB for example) in Nautilus it first copies a part of it and then it just crashes. This started recently and I have no idea why.

I was on 4.15 kernel, now I've tried 4.19.2-041902-generic and this didn't change.

I can't find anyone else having this issue.

I tried qBittorrent, it just crashes when trying to load a large file. As for suggested Thunar, I can't actually install it, because of broken openssl problem which I wasn't able to get around despite a very long time investment. (/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found)

I guess, I'll just give up and do a full reinstall. Sucks that the new Ubuntu is coming out in less than a month and this version didn't last till then, I guess..

EDIT:

Thanks for the tip! I removed my half-assed 1.1.1d openssl installation and OpenSSL-dependant programs started working normally!

As for copying large files, Thunar crashed while copying a 22Gb file saying

`File size limit exceeded (core dumped)`

and generated this crash report https://gist.github.com/ibmua/bc323bd461b614f8ed5e62b823331a66
, though, more simply, when I use `cp` in terminal on a large file it crashes with `File size limit exceeded (core dumped)` after copying 8,2 GB (8 191 991 808 bytes).

Comment: 1) How large is large? 2) Please install Deluge for testing purposes only _sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y deluge_  and see if the problem persists. 3) If so, for testing, please install Thunar with _sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y thunar_ and see if the problem persists. - Please click [edit] and let us know the results of 1-3..

Comment: Why is it looking for libraries in `/usr/local/lib`? Have you installed software manually, outside apt? If so, what software and which versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that happens when [you have a limit imposed by the *root user*](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/file-size-limit-exceeded-error-under-linux-and-solution/).

Comment: Oh, yes, sure! I changed `/etc/security/limits.conf` a while back trying to circumvent a ulimit on file size for terminal apps. And I inadvertently set up a new limit as a result, it seems. Raised that limit, rebooted into my user and it works fine now! Thanks a lot!